# what's the encoding of CentOS5.5 Linux without being set

Tags: linux, encoding, centos

As the title above said, I have a CentOS5.5 with /etc/sysconfig/i18n:

```
LANG="en_US"
#SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

and the output of locale is:

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

I see nothing about encoding, what's the default encoding if not set?

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on the locale. For en_US it's ISO 8859-1.

Comment: thanks for your reply, you mean I will get ISO 8859-1 encoding if I just set language to en_US according to locale, right?